# Binding empty controls to gridview and retrieving their values

Tags: c#, gridview

**I binded a gridview using list**

```
private void BindEntirePropertyGrid()
{
    List<Tbl_RoomMaster> items = new List<Tbl_RoomMaster>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(bedrooms.Text); i++)
    {
        items.Add(objRoomMaster);
    }
    ViewState["GridView1"] = items;
    GridView1.DataSource = items;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

**Now i tried to retrieve the values,But Showing Error**

```
if (ViewState["GridView1"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["GridView1"];
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    Label box1 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("lblbedroom");
                    DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("ddpAccomodates");
                    DropDownList box3 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("ddpBathroom");
                    DropDownList box4 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("ddpBedType");
                    //get the values from the TextBoxes
                    //then add it to the collections with a comma "," as the delimited values
                    sc.Add("BedRoom" + box1.Text + "," + box2.SelectedItem.Value + "," + box3.SelectedItem.Value + "," + box4.SelectedItem.Value);
                    rowIndex++;
                }
                //Call the method for executing inserts
                InsertRoomDetails(sc, propIDreturnedOnSave);
            }
        }
```

**Is there any other way to bind empty controls to gridview and retrieve values ?**

**The ERROR**
In this line :

DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["GridView1"];

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CT.Bussiness.Tbl_RoomMaster]' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.
```

Comment: what is the text of the error

Comment: What is the error you're getting? By the way, the contents of the `ViewState["GridView1"]` is not a `DataTable`

Comment: On which event you try to get values like that ?

Comment: **The ERROR **
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CT.Bussiness.Tbl_RoomMaster]' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the ViewState["GridView1"] is not a DataTable.

Change

```
DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["GridView1"];
```

to

```
List<Tbl_RoomMaster> dtCurrentTable = (List<Tbl_RoomMaster>)ViewState["GridView1"];
```

You would also have to change

```
if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
```

to

```
if (dtCurrentTable.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Count; i++)
```

Comment: **Now error moved to next line**

'System.Collections.Generic.List<CT.Bussiness.Tbl_RoomMaster>' does not contain a definition for 'Rows'

Comment: See my edit. You'll have to change the other stuff that reference dtCurrentTable since it's no longer a `DataTable`

Comment: **tat worked riki...thanks a lot 

and Thanks to STACK Guys for this wonderful site..**

Comment: Glad to be of help :) It would be great if you can accept this as the correct answer.